# PostgreSQL LIKE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause, sql-like

I want to get sales with date, which started with'2007-02':

```
SELECT *
FROM payment
WHERE payment_date LIKE '2007%';
```

But there is the error:

```
ERROR: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
LINE 9: WHERE payment_date LIKE '2007%'
                            ^
HINT: Operator with given name and argument types could not be found. Perhaps you should add explicit casts.
```

But another query as

```
SELECT email
FROM customer
WHERE first_name = 'Kelly' 
AND last_name LIKE 'K%';
```

work proper. How can i force this query to work?
You can get my learning database via link: https://dropmefiles.com/LX8cu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get sales with date, which started with '2007-02':

`LIKE`  is a *string* function. As the error message indicates, the `payment_date` column is of `timestamp` datatype, so use date filtering:

```
where payment_date >= date '2007-02-01' and payment_date < date '2017-03-01'
```

Or, if you want the whole year:

```
where payment_date >= date '2007-01-01' and payment_date < date '2018-01-01'
```

You might be tempted to use a date function to extract the year part of the date, and use it for comparison:

```
where extract(year from payment_date) = 2007
```

I would not recommend that; this is far less efficient, because the function needs to be applied to the entire column before the filtering can happen, as opposed to the direct filtering against literals. One says that the expression is not SARGable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message really says it all - the `like` operator takes strings on both its sides, while you have a timestamp.

An alternative approach could be to `extract` the year:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   payment
WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM payment_date) = 2007;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your fiel payment_date is of type date, time or timestamp.

Try to convert the date/time into string before using the like operator.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html